# Java Regular Expression (greedy/nongreedy)

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy, non-greedy

So I'm trying to separate the following two groups formatted as:

```
FIRST - GrouP              second.group.txt
```

The first group can contain any character
The second group is a dot(.) delimited string.

I'm using the following regex to separate these two groups:

```
([A-Z].+).*?([a-z]+\.[a-z]+)
```

However, it gives a wrong result:

```
1: FIRST - GrouP second.grou
2: p.txt
```

I don't understand because I'm using "nongreedy" separater (.*?) instead of the greedy one (. *)

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want [`([A-Z].+?)\s*\b([a-z]+(?:\.[a-z]+)+)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/dC9pT1/1) ?

Comment: @anubhava it works! Btw, what does the colon (:) mean in regex?

Comment: @user2492270 `(?:)` means do not store the matched group.

Comment: @user2492270: I have converted my comment into an answer so that you can accept it (if solution works for you).

Answer (score 2):

You can this regex to match both groups:

```
\b([A-Z].+?)\s*\b([a-z]+(?:\.[a-z]+)+)\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dC9pT1/2)

**Breakup:**

```
\b               # word boundary
([A-Z].+?)       # match [A-Z] followed by 1 or more chars (lazy)
\s*              # match 0 or more spaces
\b               # word boundary
([a-z]+          # match 1 or more of [a-z] chars
(?:\.[a-z]+)+)   # match a group of dot followed by 1 or more [a-z] chars
\b               # word boundary
```

PS: `(?:..)` is used for **non-capturing group**.

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible solution that should be pretty compact:

```
(.*?-\s*\S+)|(\S+\.?)+
```

https://regex101.com/r/iW8mE5/1

It is looking for anything followed by a dash, zero or more spaces, and then non-whitespace characters.  And if it doesn't find that, it looks for non-whitespace followed by an optional decimal.